# Failed to load resource Github pages

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I've been working on this script to keep track of my finished front-end challenges but I'm getting this error saying that it cannot load the recources but the first one works perfectly. I attached an image with the console messages [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lE9f.png).

Also, that error I'm getting only when the site is deployed on GitHub pages, on local works perfectly . Any tips to fix that problem?

Link repo: https://github.com/trstefan/fmtracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change absolute path to relative path in `script.js`。

```html
  img.src = `./${project}/design/desktop-design.jpg`;
  projectLink.href = `./${project}/index.html`;
```